# WPF control with word editing capabilities and can connect text

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

**EDIT:** Dean Kuga below writes the question another way

> "I see now that you want to create a relation between non-matching
>   text blocks in different text boxes"

This is exactly my question.

I want to create a 2 or 3 column list of text boxes.  In these text boxes the user can add text and format it very basically like highlight, color and make elections bold (This part I know could be done out of the box with a RTF control).  But what I would like to be able to do is that the user could highlight something from one textbox and link it to something highlighted in another textbox.

I have added a picture with what I mean.  It probably entails creating something around the highlighted text with a unique ID and then that same id being with the other text.

How could one achieve this with WPF and how could this be saved, for example database or file?[image]

I am prepared to make my own control if that is what is required I just need some ideas on how to handle the editing of text and also how to then save it.

Comment: I think you need to start making the control and then post the code when you get stuck after you've done a little bit of research.

Comment: Not looking for a spoon feed Danielle. Just a little brainstorming on possible ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could start by downloading and analyzing the source code of [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/) to learn how WPF controls are built.

As a matter of fact, you could probably extend the existing code of their [RichTextBox](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=RichTextBox&referringTitle=Home) to add the functionality which is currently not supported by that control, call it Extended RichTextBox or something similar and create your own codeplex open source project to share that extended control.

Comment: There are many rich text controls, this being one of them. My question goes to something a little deaper then that. For example after text has been typed, them highlighted how can I in WPF "tag" this text, give it an ID or something. Maybe I could then build lines between such text.

Comment: Off the top, I'd probably use a local database like SQLite to store each word typed or pasted into the text box as an entry in the database which would allow me to assign an Id or a Tag or what ever else and as the text in the other text box is typed in or on paste event add those to the database as well and at that point you can compare the strings from one text box to to text in the other text box with a simple query and as a result do any type of UI manipulation with the text based on query results...

Comment: I see now that you want to create a relation between non-matching text blocks in different text boxes so you'd have to save that block as an entry in the database and match it to a block in another text box by using a third table or self referencing two entries based on text box Id and text block Id...